# 'list' object has not attribute 'get' Python3.8 while getting info from XML

Tags: python-3.x, xml

So I'm trying to extract info from an XML file but I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My Code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET    
file = ET.parse('db1.xml')
        drug = file.findall('drugbank/drug/products')
        f = []
        for x in drug:
            f.append(x.text)
        return f
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drugbank xmlns="http://www.drugbank.ca" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd" version="5.1" exported-on="2019-07-02">
    <drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13" updated="2019-06-04">
        <products>
            <product>
              <name>Refludan</name>
              <labeller>Bayer</labeller>
              <ndc-id/>
              <ndc-product-code/>
              <dpd-id>02240996</dpd-id>
              <ema-product-code/>
              <ema-ma-number/>
              <started-marketing-on>2000-01-31</started-marketing-on>
              <ended-marketing-on>2013-07-26</ended-marketing-on>
              <dosage-form>Powder, for solution</dosage-form>
              <strength>50 mg</strength>
              <route>Intravenous</route>
              <fda-application-number/>
              <generic>false</generic>
              <over-the-counter>false</over-the-counter>
              <approved>true</approved>
              <country>Canada</country>
              <source>DPD</source>
            </product>
        </products>
    </drug>
</drugbank>
```

I also tried using `drug = file.findall('drugbank/drug/products/name')` instead of `drug = file.findall('drugbank/drug/products')` but it still gave the same error.

Comment: what output are you getting if you print result of selector `drugbank` only ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat []. Empty list

Comment: thats the reason its not working . so even if you try just `drugbank/drug/` you will be getting the same error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: After your ET.parse line add this n try : `root = file.getroot()

print(root.findall('./drugbank/drug/products'))`

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat still returns empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue . Use this code to get the names of your products :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drugbank xmlns="http://www.drugbank.ca" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd" version="5.1" exported-on="2019-07-02">
    <drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13" updated="2019-06-04">
        <products>
            <product>
              <name>Refludan</name>
              <labeller>Bayer</labeller>
              <ndc-id/>
              <ndc-product-code/>
              <dpd-id>02240996</dpd-id>
              <ema-product-code/>
              <ema-ma-number/>
              <started-marketing-on>2000-01-31</started-marketing-on>
              <ended-marketing-on>2013-07-26</ended-marketing-on>
              <dosage-form>Powder, for solution</dosage-form>
              <strength>50 mg</strength>
              <route>Intravenous</route>
              <fda-application-number/>
              <generic>false</generic>
              <over-the-counter>false</over-the-counter>
              <approved>true</approved>
              <country>Canada</country>
              <source>DPD</source>
            </product>
        </products>
    </drug>
</drugbank>
'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

# print(root.findall('{http://www.drugbank.ca}drug'))
ns = {'drug_bank': 'http://www.drugbank.ca'}

for drug in root.findall('drug_bank:drug', ns):
  for products in drug.findall('drug_bank:products', ns):
    for product in products.findall('drug_bank:product', ns):
      for nametag in product.findall('drug_bank:name', ns):
        print(nametag.text)
```

Output : Refludan

Explanation :

First I printed `root` and got this :

```
<Element '{http://www.drugbank.ca}drugbank' at 0x7f688ffc0770>
```

So I realised this was Namespace-XML-pattern to be used. 
Here is the link to help you understand the topic  - https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces